# Meaning of !! operator in F# (.fsx)

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I'm looking at a FAKE build script that was auto-generated through an FsLab template. In front of one of the strings in a "let" binding, the !! operator is used. What is the meaning of the !! operator?

Looking on the [Microsoft Docs F# Symbols and Operator Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/), the !! operator is not listed.

Here is the code in question, the !! operator is in the third-to-last line:

```
#r "./packages/build/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"

open Fake
open System

let buildDir  = "./build/"
let appReferences = !! "/**/*.fsproj"
let dotnetcliVersion = "2.0.2"
let mutable dotnetExePath = "dotnet"
```

Further down, the appReferences identifier is used as following:

```
Target "Restore" (fun _ ->
    appReferences
    |> Seq.iter (fun p ->
        let dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName p
        runDotnet dir "restore"
    )
)
```

Comment: Note that in F# an operator is usually just a function, and your IDE will probably give you some documentation if you hover over it. And if it is a custom operator defined in your own code then you can also go to its definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes file pattern and returns a collection of files matching the pattern.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense based on how it is used in the code that I encountered. Do you know if this is a standard operator or is it perhaps something that gets defined elsewhere when running a fake build script?

Comment: @JohnHenderson Fake has its own DSL, some of the operators follow other build systems (maybe Ant?).

Comment: As @s952163 said, the `!!` operator isn't a standard F# operator, it's defined by Fake. Specifically, it's defined [here](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/a1a090e5db1d50c1ad549d076286716a9ed042bf/src/app/Fake.Core.Globbing/GlobbingFileSystem.fs#L163) along with another couple of globbing operators: `++` to add another set of files, and `--` to remove a file pattern (e.g., "except for files that match this"). So you could, for example, build a list of files by doing `!! "*.docx" ++ "*.xlsx" -- "*.draft.docx" -- "*.draft.xlsx` if you wanted all Word and Excel documents except for drafts.